# WEBGL P5js not showing image as texture

Tags: javascript, webgl, textures, p5.js, plane

I'm trying to use an image as a texture for a plane in P5js using WEBGL, but for some reason it isn't working.

I've tried to get rid of all the lighting and just use ambientLight() but still it isn't showing. I've tried in a new sketch with just the plane and the same code and it works fine, so I don't understand what the problem is in this sketch?

```
let bodyShape;
let spacing = 50;
let bgTexture;


function preload() {
  bodyShape = loadModel('Human_body_with_net.obj');
  bgTexture = loadImage('assets/gormleyline.jpeg');
}

function setup() {
  createCanvas(600, 600,WEBGL);
  noStroke();
}

function draw() {
  background(0);
  
  debugMode();
  orbitControl();

  ambientLight(255);
  // pointLight(102,0,0,0,1,0);
  // pointLight(0,102,255,1,0,0);
  // directionalLight(255,0,0,0,1,0);
  // directionalLight(255,255,255,0,0,-1);
  // pointLight(0,0,0,mouseX,mouseY,0);
  backgroundShape();

  push();
  translate(-260,0,0); 
  for (let x = 0; x<10; x++){    
  bodyFunction(x+spacing,0,0);
  rotateX(50);
  }
  pop();
}

function bodyFunction(x,y,z,rotation){
  specularMaterial(255);
  translate(x,y,z);
  rotateX(HALF_PI);
  model(bodyShape);

}

function backgroundShape(){
  push();
  translate(0,0,-130);
  plane(600,600);
    texture(bgTexture)
  pop();
}
```

Here's the link to the sketch in case it's useful: https://editor.p5js.org/rociorey/sketches/4H1eFQpKh

Thank you!

Comment: is the issue solved?

Answer (score 1):

You must specify the texture for the geometry before you draw the geometry (see [`texture()`](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/texture)):

```js
texture(bgTexture);
plane(600,600);
```